# CharacterData Not Visible?

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, soap-client, cdata

I am trying to get the data inside of a CDATA SOAP Element.

To do so, I have followed the instructions provided by [How can SOAPMessage parse <![CDATA[ ]]>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971116/how-can-soapmessage-parse-cdata).

This and other examples require me to use the following code segments:

```
SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
NodeList nodeList = soapBody.getElementsByTagName("outerElementOfCDATA");
Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
Node child = element.getFirstChild();
String characterData;
if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
    characterData = ((CharacterData) child).getData();
}
```

However, when I try to use "instanceof CharacterData", I get an error saying CharacterData is not visible.  (For reference:  I am getting this information from eclipse)

It doesn't make any sense to me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (I searched more thoroughly and found an answer):

```
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
```

Don't use the standard CharacterData from java.lang.